# Mysql statement to return primary key with no foreign key?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to query a database for nodes that dont have a relationship aka foreign key. I tried this join statement but it didnt work

```
SELECT nodes.*, relationships.* FROM nodes inner JOIN relationships ON nodes.id = null;
```

how can I display only the nodes that dont have a relationship? thank you

```
nodes                 Relationships                      
-----                 -------------
id int(11),           id int(11),
name varchar(35),     to int(11), //this is the destination node from the id relation 
color varchar(7),     data varchar(0) null
type varchar (12),    Foreign key (id) references nodes(id)
Primary key (id)       

engine = innodb
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `ON nodes.id = null` you must use column names in `ON` statement with join. if  you want to set `nodes.id = null`, use it in `where`

```
SELECT 
    nodes.*
FROM 
    nodes left JOIN relationships ON nodes.id = Relationships.id
where
    Relationships.id is null;
```

Comment: yeah the null wasnt a good idea since it return an empty set, how can I query this database to show me the nodes that dont have any foreign keys?

Comment: yeah it keeps telling me this error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where
    relationships.id is null' at line 1

Comment: this be default wont work, because relationships with id null will not be linked to a node so only selecting relationships with null will result in 0 records

Comment: Nope. `left join` will result those nodes which doesn't have any relations, have null value as relation id. So we can filter them using `where`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT `to` from Relationships);
```

This returns the nodes which dont have an id in the Relationships table

also best practise is to only use lowercase in your database cause some databases are case sensitive and others aren't.

Comment: hey joel I actually got an error when doing the query, what does this mean? #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: use \`to\` because to is a reserved word in mysql.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'to' in 'field list'

Comment: Yeah it still gives me the error and the tables are the same. the sql statement I use is SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT `to` from relationships);

Comment: Im using myphpadmin if that says anything.